# MacBook Pro M1 13" macOS Monterey can't set external display as main display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, monterey

In the display settings, I tried to drag the menu bar from the laptop display to the external screen, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the status of "Displays have separate Spaces" in Mission Control prefs. It may only work if that is *off*. [Can't test, hate changing that parameter as it messes badly with my workflow]

Comment: @Tetsujin Kudos to you, I turned that off and rebooted, this fixed my problem. However, does this mean it's impossible to have separate spaces for each display?

Comment: Yes, it's an either/or. With separate spaces the menu bar & dock move to the active window each time. Without it, you can set them to define the main display.